# .NET Framework 4.6.2 to 4.7.2

Tags: .net, vb.net

I tried to migrate a library targeted at .NET Framework 4.6.2 to 4.7.2.

When testing the code, I got a Class Exists exception in my WndProc override sub. It looks like there may have been a change in the way constructors are processed. Here is the scenario on which my question is based...

```
Public Sub New (arg1 as string)
    Me.New(arg1, arg2_DefaultValue)
End Sub

Public Sub New(arg1 as String, arg2 as Integer)
    MyBase.New
    <some processing>
End Sub
```

With 4.7.2, does the class get created when the first New is called or is there some other reason I need to find for the Class Exists exception when running the code with 4.7.2?

Many thanks for any help or advice.

Here is my WndProc code in case it is relevant...

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Integer = &HA2
    Const HTCLOSE As Integer = 20
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN
            If CInt(m.WParam) = HTCLOSE Then
                Return
            End If
        Case WM_NCLBUTTONUP
            If CInt(m.WParam) = HTCLOSE Then
                MsClose.PerformClick()
                Return
            End If
    End Select
    MyBase.WndProc(m) ' Exception thrown here
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you also have the empty constructor (`Public Sub New ()`)? Remove `MyBase.New`.

Comment: Yes, I have Public Sub New(), which should throw an exception. MyBase.New is required because the class inherits Form.

Comment: `Public Sub New()` must not throw anything. `MyBase.New` is not required. The constructor of the base class is called in any case. See that you don't have duplicate `WndProc`.

Comment: Can you show us the EXACT exception message?  As far as I know, there is no such thing as a "Class Exists Exception".

Comment: Please explain. The New() is an illegal call and I thought MyBase.New was required to perform the default constructor processes. Has this changed from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2? Thanks

Comment: The Exact message is "Class already exists"

Comment: Without the class details (post the definition, at least; is it just `Public Class MyClass Inherits Form`? ) it's a guess game. Move `MyBase.WndProc(m)` before  `Select Case` and set `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero` instead of `Return`.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. I would very much like to understand why this works on .NET Framework 4.6.2 and not 4.7.2 so that I can ensure that other library functions and classes will work correctly on 4.7.2. I have reverted to 4.6.2 until I can understand what needs to be changed for 4.7.2.

Comment: It is Public Class MyClass Inherits Form. Running a trace on WndProc, the Case is never met, so I doubt any change in sequence or processing would produce a different result.

Comment: Move all the `const` declarations outside that method. As fields in the main class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are you saying that Framework 4.7.2 no longer allows Const definitions in a Sub?